# WPF Desktop Application Notification Not Showing

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application

I want to show Desktop Toast Notification in my WPF application. I write some code for that but it's not working. Code Execute properly but notification not showing.

```
 var message = "Sample message";
        var xml = $"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><toast><visual>" +
            $"<binding template=\"ToastText01\">" +
            $"<text id=\"1\">{message}</text></binding>" +
            $"</visual></toast>";
        var toastXml = new XmlDocument();
        toastXml.LoadXml(xml);
        var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("Sample toast").Show(toast);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: "...not working..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: @JohnB Yes, I'm Debug the code, Not getting any error Message, The code is executed properly but notification not showing.

Comment: `ToastNotificationManager` is part of UWP, not WPF